# What Causes Low Page Fullness with Low Fragmentation

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a non-clustered index with the following Page Fullness = 76.35 % Total Fragmentation = 4.70 % Pages = 10211

I have not set a fill factor on it (it shows 0 as the fill factor).

What would cause the page fullness to be low but the fragmentation be low too?

We are experiencing some sql timeouts while inserting new records and I was wondering if this could be causing it.

Comment: Recommended fill factor value is 90

Comment: This sort of fill rate is usually caused by lots of page splits. If rows are added to the index in an effectively random order, random pages will split at random times. Each split will leave two pages with about 50% fill. Based on my rough calculations, an index working this way would have an average page fill of about 75%, which is about what you have.

Comment: what would account for a similar situation as AWeim 's situation except for with a clustered index given it is indexed by an ever-increasing integer (with identity)?

Comment: Can you post your table definition?

Comment: "We are experiencing some sql timeouts while inserting new records and I was wondering if this could be causing it." The probability of that is vanishingly small. Even if a page split occurs and the insert is "expensive", the increase in time will not reach timeout levels. If this is the problem you're trying to solve, stop thinking and *look*. Hook up a profiler and see what's happening when the inserts time out. Check for locks taking a long time, deadlocks or resource-intensive queries happening concurrently.

Answer (score -1):

The comment from Laughing Vergil answered my question.  Thank you.